# Change TextButton border colour - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added a border to my TextButton.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)))),
  onPressed: () {
    replacePoints();
  },
  child: Text(
    "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.replacePoints} +",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ))
```

How can I change its colour (only outline colour not background)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.red, // your color here
              width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)))),
    onPressed: () {
      replacePoints();
    },
    child: Text(
      "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.replacePoints} +",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code you will change Border color in two ways

1. Using **`TextButton.styleFrom`** refer [`styleFrom`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/styleFrom.html)

   ```
   TextButton(
         style: TextButton.styleFrom(
           side: BorderSide(
             color: Colors.green,
           ),
         ),
         onPressed: () {
           //write your onPressed function here
           print('Button Press');
         },
         child: Text(
           'Hello, World!',
           style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
         ),
       ),
   ```

Result-> [image]

2. Using **`ButtonStyle`** Class refer [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html)

   ```
   TextButton(
     style: ButtonStyle(
       shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
         RoundedRectangleBorder(
           side: BorderSide(
             color: Colors.blue,
           ),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
         ),
       ),
     ),
     onPressed: () {
       //write your onPressed function here
       print('Button Press');
     },
     child: Text(
       'Hello, World!',
       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
     ),
   ),
   ```

Result-> [image]